# Apache Reverse proxy using hosts file

Tags: apache, configuration, proxy

I have set up the following config for my apache server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.tld.com
    ServerAlias *.tld.com

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.+) $1 [P]
    ProxyPassReverse / $1


</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.tld.com
    ServerAlias *.tld.com
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key

    ProxyPass / http://localhost/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/
</VirtualHost>
```

And then I set up my host file to look like this:

```
127.0.0.1 tld.com
external_ip sub.tld.com
external_ip_2 sub.tld.com
```

external_ip and external_ip_2 are two servers that run apache and have vhosts as well. For the main domain I have a wildcard CSS and added a wildcard DNS record.

The proxying works perfect with HTTP and HTTPS as well, for all the servers that are in my /etc/hosts file. But it seems that when I try to resolve a subdomain that is not in my hosts file, apache get's stuck and in the logs I can see the following error:

```
[pid 4690] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

I think that there is an infinite loop and I don't know why this is caused. I consider that the page from the proxy server should be displayed if the subdomain is not resolved by the hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the ServerName be like the domain name, and the alias the www ? Like:

```
ServerName tld.com
ServerAlias www.tld.com
```

Seems a bit redundant to me to put the ServerName as a subdomain, an then add an alias with a wildcard.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the problem in any way.